# Django - Is it possible to make a redirect from a function in a view?

Tags: django, view, return, decorator, httpresponse

I try to call a function which checks a rule and if the rule is not fulfilled I'd like to skip the rest of the view code and just return a HttpResponse Error.

I'd like to put all the escaping logic in a function because I need it at several points all over my project.

I tried to do something like this:

```
def myView(request):

    checkFunction()
```

And:

```
def checkFunction():
    #do stuff
    return HttpResponse(status=403)
```

But it just don't work (no wonder)...

Any ideas how to do this right?

Thanks

Ron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a decorator for applying a logic to a view with possible redirect(if you can really put your logic outside the view).

```
def check_my_logic(view):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some logic here
        if all_ok:
             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=403)
  return wrap
```

and then in views.py:

```
 from mydecorators import check_my_logic

 @check_my_logic
 def some_view(request):
     ....
```

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is, in `myView` function, you call your `checkFunction`, but you do not use the return value of `checkFunction` so your return value of  `checkFunction` `return HttpResponse(status=403)` got lost and never returned within `myView`.

It might be like:

```
def myView(request):

    result = checkFunction()
    if result:
        return result
    #if no problem, keep running on...



def checkFunction():
    #do stuff
    if something_goes_wrong:
        return HttpResponse(status=403)
    # you do not need to return anything if no error occured...
```

So, if nothing goes wrong, then `checkFunction` will not return anything, and `result` will be `None` and `if result:` block will not be executed. If you return a response, than your view will return that response (in your situation, `HttpResponse(status=403)`)...

UPDATE: Then you can do this....

```
def checkFunction(request):
    #do stuff
    if something_goes_wrong:
        return HttpResponse(status=403)
    elif some_other_issue:
        return HttpResponse(....)
    else: #no problems, everything is as expected...
        return render_to_response(...) # or any kind of response you want

def myView(request):

    return checkFunction(request)
```

this way, your view will return what your `checkFunction` returns...

Also, passing `request` object to your `checkFunction` might be necessary since you wish to creeate your response there. You might need it.

Comment: i was quite sure this was the reason but couldnt figure out a solution. yours is nice but still i'd like to put everything into one function... but thanks anyway :)